# How to automatical add data to a table with a foreign key php [MariaDB]

Tags: php, mariadb

How can I use php to add data to the foreign such that the IDs match:

In this example, I have a table for a 'member' and a separate table for 'emails'. A member can have multiple emails and therefore a separate table is created that stores emails with the member ID as a foreign key.

How can I write code that inserts data into both tables when fields have been submitted?

My most recent (unsuccessful) attempt:

PHP block:

```
$query=
"INSERT INTO Members(FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, TITLE, INSTITUTION) VALUES ('$first_name',
'$last_name','$title','$institution');
INSERT INTO EMAIL(Members_ID, EMAIL) VALUES
(LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$email');
INSERT INTO WEBSITE(Members_ID, WEBSITE) VALUES
(LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$website');";
mysqli_query($connection,$query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

SQL Block:

```
CREATE TABLE Members(
    ID  INT  UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
    FIRST_NAME  TEXT(16),
    LAST_NAME  TEXT(16,
    TITLE  TEXT(7), /** 7 CHARS for  'Student'*/
    INSTITUTION  VARCHAR(2048),
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
  );
  CREATE TABLE EMAIL(
    Members_ID  INT  UNSIGNED NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    EMAIL  VARCHAR(2048),
    FOREIGN KEY (Members_ID) REFERENCES Members(ID)
  );
  CREATE TABLE WEBSITE(
    Members_ID  INT  UNSIGNED NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    WEBSITE  VARCHAR(2048),
    FOREIGN KEY (Members_ID) REFERENCES Members(ID)
  );
```

Comment: If a member is already in the table, the `INSERT` will fail, and you won't have the id.  See IODKU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use, for example [mysqli_multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php), after having retrieved the ID assigned to the first insertion (I wouldn't rely too much on the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in this case):

```
$conn = mysqli_connect(...);

$query = "INSERT INTO Members (FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,TITLE,INSTITUTION) VALUES ('$first_name','$last_name','$title','$institution')";
mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$lid = mysqli_insert_id($conn);   

$query  = "INSERT INTO EMAIL (Members_ID,EMAIL) VALUES ($lid,'$email');";
$query .= "INSERT INTO WEBSITE (Members_ID,WEBSITE) VALUES ($lid,'$website');";
mysqli_multi_query($conn, $query);
```